# shopify hydrogen and sass setup

Tags: sass, shopify-hydrogen

hi can somebody explain me how to setup sass module in hydrogen project.
I looked in the documentation but nothing really helpfull.
I ve tried also to add sass dependency but still doesn't recognize my sass file.

Answer (score 0):

I just install sass module and then make files on each component named `styles.module.scss` and it works perfectly.

```
npm install sass --save-dev
```

Comment: How did you install sass modules? I can't find any documentation for getting CSS Modules or Sass Modules working with Hydrogen V2.

Comment: Just add "sass" to devDependencies. I don't remember right now but I think this should work: npm install sass --save-dev

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work. Even after running `npm install sass --save-dev`, you get this error `[ERROR] No loader is configured for ".scss" files: app/styles/app.scss` when you replace `import styles from './styles/app.css';` with `import styles from './styles/app.scss'; in **app/root.tsx**. Are you sure you are using Hydrogen V2? Because sass works out-of-box in V1 as it uses Vite (which supports sass)