# How can you use Sass Modules with Shopify Hydrogen V2?

Tags: sass, css-modules, remix, shopify-hydrogen, sass-modules

I'm exploring using Hydrogen instead of Next.js Commerce for building out an ecommerce platform that I'm working on, but the only styling option for Hydrogen V2 seems to be tailwind or vanilla CSS. I can't find any documentation anywhere for using Sass Modules or even just CSS Modules like with Next.js.

Comment: I think this should work ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160923/shopify-hydrogen-and-sass-setup